# Calculations with latitude and longitude

Tags: javascript, eclipse, google-maps

I get my position using :

```
var myLat = position.coords.latitude;
var myLng = position.coords.longitude;
```

I have to do some calculations with this 2 variables, but eclipse show me an error saying that myLat is NaN. I insert an alert: `alert(myLat)` but show me "myLat" instead the value of my coordinate.

So, I can't do calculations. How can I convert myLat in a value that allows me perform calculations?

I use MVC pattern, so myLat and myLng is declared like that in Model:

```
var posAttuale = function(){
    this.myLat = "myLat";
    this.myLng = "myLng";
    this.myComune = "myComune";
};
```

In Controller:

```
var infoPos = new posAttuale();

infoPos.myLat = position.coords.latitude;
infoPos.myLng= position.coords.longitude;
```

I'm using eclipse and a Samsung Galaxy S4Mini.

Comment: There must be something wrong with `myLat` and how you're accessing it.  Can you show mor code?  As a tip, look at using `console.log(somValue)` in a debugger on your browser such as Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools

Comment: @RobSchmuecker I insert more code and information

Comment: There must be something else going on http://jsfiddle.net/Lzsb5hh0/ shows that it works fine.

Comment: but in that case coordinates are static. I have to retrieve my position automatically

Comment: In which case your position hasn't loaded yet from google maps API as it is an *asynchronous* call.  You will need to do something in the `callback` of when the position returns successfully to make this work.